# I can't install Parcel using npm - Failed to parse package.json data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm

I created package.json file using (npm init) in cmd in project folder
,then i wrote
(npm i parcel --save-dev)
and this what i got :

```
C:\Users\XPRESS\Desktop\starter>npm i parcel --save-dev
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file C:\Users\XPRESS\Desktop\starter\package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token } in JSON at position 211 while parsing nea
r '...dex.html",
npm ERR! JSON.parse
npm ERR! JSON.parse   },
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "author": "Ibra...'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\XPRESS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-25T18_59_41
_237Z-debug.log
```

and this package.json

```
{
  "name": "starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Recipe application",
  "main": "index.html",
  
    "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html",
      
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

please any ideas .. I'm new and i can't find any solutions for 4 days

Comment: Post your package.json file.

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Remove the comma from `"build": "parcel build index.html",`.

Comment: @VassilisPallas consider not answering in the comments but just post an answer. Even if it is simple :)

Comment: thanks adriano .. that was helpful.

Comment: @PascalLamers he did

Comment: @NoTimeForCaution weird the site must bugged for me :) the answer didn't pop up for me before ! cheers !

Comment: @PascalLamers This is not even a correct structured question.

Comment: @VassilisPallas what ?

Comment: @PascalLamers This question should be closed. The error explains what the issue was. Furthermore, I really doubt if there was an investigation before asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove extra trailing comma at this line:

```
"build": "parcel build index.html"
```

Comment: That was helpful. I read it .. thanks so much.